# boost asio async udp server - poor performance

Tags: c++, performance, asynchronous, udp, boost-asio

I wrote an boost asio async udp server and measured the time on a client from before a short ping message was sent to after the returning ping message was received. I measured this in my home network so I expected the results to be really good.

Unfortunately the average time it took the message to get to the my other computer and back was always around 4ms (tested in 2 different local networks).

As I wrote the simplest server possible I am now wondering if and how I can improve the performance.

**.hpp**:

```
class udp_server2 {
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::streambuf read_buffer;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint read_endpoint;

    void receive();
    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    void send(const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint& endpoint, const boost::asio::streambuf& data);
    void handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

public:
    udp_server2(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);
};
```

**.cpp**:

```
udp_server2::udp_server2(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
    socket(io_service, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 1337)) {
    receive();
}


void udp_server2::receive() {
    socket.async_receive_from(read_buffer.prepare(10000), read_endpoint, boost::bind(&udp_server2::handle_receive, this, _1, _2));
}

void udp_server2::handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
        read_buffer.commit(14);
        send(read_endpoint, read_buffer);
    }
    receive();
}

void udp_server2::send(const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint& endpoint, const boost::asio::streambuf& data) {
    socket.async_send_to(read_buffer.data(), endpoint, boost::bind(&udp_server2::handle_send, this, _1, _2));
}

void udp_server2::handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
        read_buffer.consume(14);
    }
}
```

**Can the performance of this asio server be significantly improved or do I have to switch to another library?**

Comment: Could this poor performance be explained by the network itself ?

Comment: Hm as I said I tested on two separate networks. I am also not sure what would be the minimum time requiered.

Comment: Indeed but if your two separate networks have the same characteristics ... In my experience network limitations are often the bottleneck. But then again I'm no expert in that matter, just expressing what I've experienced mostly so far. Interesting question you have here anyway. Upvote and favorite, definitely want to get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I tried to run both client and server on the same computer (via localhost).

I got a response time of 0.2ms. So I conclude that **the poor performance was infact because of the network delay**. In both test environments a fritzbox was used as router so this was probably the bottleneck.